# Using Global variable in my wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use a global variable to speed up my plugin, because i'm using the same variable on several functions like so:

```
$ftp43_inputtypes = array();

function ftp_get_input_types(){
  global $ftp43_inputtypes;
  /*...*/
 foreach($form->find('input') as $input){
  array_push($input_types, array(
                 'type' => $input->getAttribute('type'),
                 'name' => $input->getAttribute('name'),
            ));
   }
  $ftp43_inputtypes = $input_types;
}
```

And then use my `$ftp43_inputtypes` variable for the a whole lot of functions.

```
function myotherfunction1(){
    global $ftp43_inputtypes;
    echo $ftp43_inputtypes;
}
function myotherfunction2(){
    global $ftp43_inputtypes;
    echo $ftp43_inputtypes;
}
```

...
it's not working i'm getting an error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function get_page_permastruct() on a non-object.`

I know that it's a bad practice to use it on wordpress development, but how can I use `$ftp43_inputtypes` as global variable and use it on other functions?

Comment: Where, in the code you have shown us, does it mention get_page_permastruct ?

Comment: The function get_page_permastruct exist on the WordPress core, this error pop up when there is something wrong with the WordPress environment and global execution.

Comment: So why do you think that the code you have added/shown us here has anything to do with the error?

Comment: I don't know, I'm just looking for a way to use global variables in wordpress